# Can I use an external diff/merge tool within the Eclipse "Team Synchronization" perspective?

Tags: eclipse, merge

In the **Synchronize** tab of the Eclipse **Team Synchronization** perspective, double-clicking a file shows the built-in 2-way diff/merge editor. If I install an external merge utility, this is not used in the **Team Synchronization** perspective--it can only be accessed from the **Edit Conflicts...** menu item. It would be much nicer to have a 3-way merge tool appear as the editor inside **Team Synchronization**. Does anyone know of a way to configure Eclipse to do this? Thanks in advance.

Byron

Comment: Hi Byron, did you ever solve this?  Have been struggling to find a solution to this myself.  When you say you can access external merge tool from the Edit Conflicts menu item, where is this in Eclipse?

Comment: There's an "edit conflicts" dialog within the Perforce plugin.  I miss SVN.

Answer (score 1):

Subversive plugin for SVN can help out. Check this [link](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/preferences/pref_diff_viewer.php) for configuring subversive to use an external diff tool.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to integrate Beyond Compare tool inside Eclipse, use the [link](http://beyondcvs.sourceforge.net/update/0.8.x/) and install eclipse plugin.

Please look at this answer also [Need help configuring external diff with Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4276349)